INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes: this error occurs when I change the batch size of a encoder-decoder using LSTM
I am doing a task of time series prediction using Encoder-Decoder. This is my model:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr  9 23:59:31 2024

@author: ASUS
"""

from library import *

class LuongAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units):
      super(LuongAttention, self).__init__()
      self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
      self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
      self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
      
  def call(self, query, values):
      #print('\n******* Luong Attention  STARTS******')
      #print('query (decoder hidden state): (batch_size, hidden size) ', query.shape)
      #print('values (encoder all hidden state): (batch_size, max_len, hidden size) ', values.shape)
      
      # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
      # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
      # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
      # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
      query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)
      
      #print('query_with_time_axis:(batch_size, 1, hidden size) ', query_with_time_axis.shape)
      
      
      values_transposed = tf.transpose(values, perm=[0, 2, 1])
      #print('values_transposed:(batch_size, hidden size, max_len) ', values_transposed.shape)
      
      # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
      # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
      # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
      #BAHDANAU ADDITIVE:
      score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
          self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))
    
      #LUONGH Dot-product
      #score = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(query_with_time_axis, values_transposed) , perm=[0, 2, 1])

      #print('score: (batch_size, max_length, 1) ',score.shape)
      # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
      attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)
      #print('attention_weights: (batch_size, max_length, 1) ',attention_weights.shape)
      # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
      context_vector = attention_weights * values
      #print('context_vector before reduce_sum: (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size) ',context_vector.shape)
      context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)
      #print('context_vector after reduce_sum: (batch_size, hidden_size) ',context_vector.shape)
      

      #print('\n******* Luong Attention ENDS******')
      return context_vector, attention_weights

#%%
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, 
                 lstm_units, 
                 dropout_rate, 
                 l2_penalty, 
                 num_features, 
                 regularization):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        self.l2_penalty = l2_penalty
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)
        if regularization:
            self.lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units[0],
                                            return_sequences = True,
                                            return_state = True,
                                            dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
                                            kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty)))
            self.lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units[0],
                                            return_sequences = True,
                                            return_state = True,
                                            dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
                                            kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty)))
            self.dense = Dense(num_features,
                               activation = 'relu',
                               kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
                               kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty))
        else:
            self.lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units[0],
                                            return_sequences = True,
                                            return_state = True,
                                            dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()))
            self.lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units[0],
                                            return_sequences = True,
                                            return_state = True,
                                            dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()))
            self.dense = Dense(num_features,
                               activation = 'relu',
                               kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())
    
    def call(self, 
             encoder_inputs, 
             training = None):
        output_lstm1, forward_state_h_lstm1, forward_state_c_lstm1, backward_state_h_lstm1, backward_state_c_lstm1  = self.lstm1(encoder_inputs, 
                                                                                                                                 #training = training
                                                                                                                                 )
        # state_h_lstm1 = tf.concat([forward_state_h_lstm1, backward_state_h_lstm1], axis = -1)
        # state_c_lstm1 = tf.concat([forward_state_c_lstm1, backward_state_c_lstm1], axis = -1)
        # states_lstm1 = [state_h_lstm1, state_c_lstm1]
        output_lstm2, forward_state_h_lstm2, forward_state_c_lstm2, backward_state_h_lstm2, backward_state_c_lstm2 = self.lstm2(output_lstm1, 
                                                                                                                                initial_state = [forward_state_h_lstm1,
                                                                                                                                                 forward_state_c_lstm1,
                                                                                                                                                 backward_state_h_lstm1,
                                                                                                                                                 backward_state_c_lstm1],
                                                                                                                                #training = training
                                                                                                                                )
        state_h_lstm2 = tf.concat([forward_state_h_lstm2, backward_state_h_lstm2], axis = -1)
        state_c_lstm2 = tf.concat([forward_state_c_lstm2, backward_state_c_lstm2], axis = -1)
        state_lstm2 = [state_h_lstm2, state_c_lstm2]
                
        # encoder_outputs: (batch_size, time step, num features), state_lstm2: a list of (batch size, lstm_units[0]*2) (due to the Bidirectional)
        return output_lstm2, state_lstm2

class DecoderBase(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, 
                 out_step, 
                 dropout_rate, 
                 #dist_size, 
                 #probabilistic,
                 l2_penalty,
                 regularization):
        super().__init__()
        self.out_step = out_step
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        #self.dist_size = dist_size
        #self.probabilistic = probabilistic
        self.base_dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)
        if regularization:
            self.base_dense = Dense(1,
                                    activation = 'relu',
                                    kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
                                    kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty))
        else:
            self.base_dense = Dense(1,
                                    activation = 'relu',
                                    kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())
    
    # Have to run one step at a time unlike with the encoder since sometimes is not teacher forcing
    def run_single_recurrent_step(self, 
                                  inputs, # (batch size, num of features) (num of features here can be 1 + 14 or 1)
                                  states, # list of 2 tensors: (batch size, num of features) (num of features here can be lstm_units[0]*2)
                                  input_sequence_data, # (batch size, time step, num of features) (num of features here can be lstm_units[0]*2)
                                  training):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
    def call(self, 
             decoder_inputs, 
             initial_inputs, 
             initial_states, 
             input_sequence_data, 
             teacher_force_prob = None, 
             training = None):
        # decoder_inputs is the labels of (batch size, time step, 1)
        # initial_inputs is the final output of the encoder outputs (batch size, num features) 
        # initial_states is the output states of the encoder: a list of 2 tensors: (batch size, lstm_units[0]*2)
        # input_sequence_data is the encoder outputs (batch size, time step, lstm_units[0]*2)
        predictions = []
        input_data = self.base_dropout(initial_inputs)
        # convert from (batch size, lstm_units[0]*2) to (batch size, 1) to ensure the congruency of the input to the LSTM cell
        input_data = self.base_dense(input_data)
        states = initial_states
        for t in range(self.out_step):
            # inputs dimension: (batch size, 1 + 14)
            inputs = input_data
            # inputs dimension: (batch size, 1)
            #inputs = input_data
            outputs, states_output = self.run_single_recurrent_step(inputs, states, input_sequence_data, training)
            predictions.append(outputs)
            teacher_force = random.random() < teacher_force_prob if teacher_force_prob is not None else False
            if teacher_force:
                input_data = decoder_inputs[:, t, :] # the input for t+1 is the label at t
            else:
                input_data = outputs # the input for t+1 is the output at t
            states = states_output
        
        outputs_predictions = tf.stack(predictions)
        outputs_predictions = tf.transpose(outputs_predictions, [1, 0, 2])
        return outputs_predictions # (batch size, time step, num of features), in this case, num of features = 1
        

class DecoderVanilla(DecoderBase):
    def __init__(self, 
                 lstm_units,
                 out_step,
                 dropout_rate,
                 #dist_size,
                 #probabilistic,
                 l2_penalty,
                 regularization):
        super().__init__(out_step, 
                         dropout_rate, 
                         #dist_size, 
                         #probabilistic, 
                         l2_penalty, 
                         regularization)
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)
        if regularization:
            self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(lstm_units[1],
                                      dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
                                      kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty))
            self.dense = Dense(1,
                               kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty)) # no need activation for the output
        else:
            self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(lstm_units[1],
                                      dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
            self.dense = Dense(1) # no need activation for the output
    
    def run_single_recurrent_step(self, 
                                  inputs, 
                                  states, 
                                  input_sequence_data, 
                                  training):
        return_outputs, return_states = self.lstm_cell(inputs, states = states,
                                                       #training = training
                                                       )
        return_outputs = self.dense(tf.concat([return_outputs, inputs], axis = -1))
        
        return return_outputs, return_states

class DecoderWithAttention(DecoderBase):
    def __init__(self,
                 lstm_units,
                 out_step,
                 dropout_rate,
                 #dist_size,
                 #probabilistic,
                 l2_penalty,
                 regularization):
        super().__init__(out_step, 
                         dropout_rate, 
                         #dist_size, 
                         #probabilistic, 
                         l2_penalty, 
                         regularization)
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.attention = LuongAttention(32)
        if regularization:
            self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(lstm_units[1],
                                      dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
                                      kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty))
            self.dense = Dense(1,
                               kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_penalty)) # no need activation for the output
        else:
            self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(lstm_units[1],
                                      dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      recurrent_dropout = dropout_rate,
                                      kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
            self.dense = Dense(1) # no need activation for the output
        
    def run_single_recurrent_step(self,
                                  inputs,
                                  states,
                                  input_sequence_data,
                                  training):
        query = states[0]
        values = input_sequence_data
        # apply attention
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(query, values)
        inputs_concat = tf.concat([context_vector, inputs], axis = -1)
        return_outputs, return_states = self.lstm_cell(inputs_concat, states = states, 
                                                       #training = training
                                                       )
        return_outputs = self.dense(tf.concat([return_outputs, inputs_concat, context_vector], axis = -1))
        
        return return_outputs, return_states

def seq2seq(encoder_input_shape,
            decoder_input_shape,
            out_step,
            num_features,
            type_decoder,
            lstm_units,
            dropout_rate,
            l2_penalty,
            teacher_force_prob,
            regularization,
            training):    
    encoder = Encoder(lstm_units, 
                      dropout_rate, 
                      l2_penalty, 
                      num_features, 
                      regularization)
    if type_decoder == 'Vanilla':
        decoder = DecoderVanilla(lstm_units, 
                                 out_step, 
                                 dropout_rate, 
                                 l2_penalty, 
                                 regularization)
    elif type_decoder == 'WithAttention':
        decoder = DecoderWithAttention(lstm_units, 
                                       out_step, 
                                       dropout_rate, 
                                       l2_penalty, 
                                       regularization)
    encoder_inputs = Input(encoder_input_shape)
    decoder_inputs = Input(decoder_input_shape)
    encoder_outputs, encoder_states = encoder(encoder_inputs, training)
    decoder_outputs = decoder(decoder_inputs, encoder_outputs[:,-1,:], encoder_states, encoder_outputs, teacher_force_prob, training)
    # Buil model
    model = Model(inputs = [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs = decoder_outputs, name = 'Seq2Seq')
    
    return model

This is the code to create the model ‘Vanilla’.
lstm_units = [32,
               2*32]
n_features = 14
dropout_rate = 0.3
 #dropout_rate = 0.3              
l2_penalty = 0.01
#l2_penalty = 0.001
batch_size = 512
n_epochs = 200
out_step = 12
regularization = True
training = True


encoder_input_shape = (12, 14)
decoder_input_shape = (12, 1)

model_vanilla = seq2seq(encoder_input_shape,
                        decoder_input_shape,
                        out_step,
                        n_features,
                        'Vanilla',
                        lstm_units,
                        dropout_rate,
                        l2_penalty,
                        teacher_force_prob = None,
                        regularization = True,
                        training = True)

This is an example of the input:
x = tf.ones(shape = (800, 12, 14))
y = tf.ones(shape = (800, 12, 1))
out = model_vanilla((x, y)) # this model takes 2 inputs

At first, the model runs well. The output shape is (800, 12, 1). However, when I change the batch size:
x = tf.ones(shape = (900, 12, 14))
y = tf.ones(shape = (900, 12, 1))
out = model_vanilla((x, y)) # this model takes 2 inputs

This error occurs:
InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lstm_cell_13" "                 f"(type LSTMCell).

{{function_node __wrapped__Mul_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} required broadcastable shapes [Op:Mul]

Call arguments received by layer "lstm_cell_13" "                 f"(type LSTMCell):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(900, 1), dtype=float32)
  • states=['tf.Tensor(shape=(900, 64), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(900, 64), dtype=float32)']
  • training=True


2024-04-18 00:44:42.125422: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1768] INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes

The error comes from:
outputs, states_output = self.run_single_recurrent_step(inputs, states, input_sequence_data, training)
return_outputs, return_states = self.lstm_cell(inputs, states = states,

So in conclusion, when I change the batch size of the input, the model does not run anymore. It raises the error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes. Can anymore figure out the reason and a solution? Thanks a lots :smiley: .
I have tried declaring the encoder and decoder seperately:
enc = Encoder(lstm_units, 
              dropout_rate, 
              l2_penalty, 
              n_features, 
              regularization)
dec = DecoderVanilla(lstm_units, 
                     out_step, 
                     dropout_rate,
                     l2_penalty, 
                     regularization)

o, s = enc(x)
d = dec(y, o[:,-1,:], s, o, teacher_force_prob = None, training = False)
d.shape

and it works for all batch size. What came across my mind is the definition of the Input in the Seq2seq function, but the definition was fine. The difference is that when I did not declared the input explicitly using Input, the code worked for all batch sizes. However, when I did, it only worked for the first batch size it calculated.
